# Prometheus: line chart (one line from many metrics)

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am a newbie in Prometheus and promql and this 2 problem:

I have n metrics. n ist dynamically, sometimes a metric will added or sometimes a metric will removed. The metrics look like

```
{__name__="my_messages", container="my_container", endpoint="http", instance="my_instance", job="my_job", namespace="my_namespace", type="my_type", pod="my_pod_uuid1", service="my_service"}
{__name__="my_messages", container="my_container", endpoint="http", instance="my_instance", job="my_job", namespace="my_namespace", type="my_type", pod="my_pod-uuid2", service="my_service"}
{__name__="my_messages", container="my_container", endpoint="http", instance="my_instance", job="my_job", namespace="my_namespace", type="my_type", pod="my_pod-uuid3", service="my_service"}
```

The difference between the metrics is the dynamically generated pod.
I show this in a lines diagram.
With the raw query

```
application_my_messages_total{namespace="my_namespace"}
```

I get 3 lines in my diagram. One line for every uuid.
Can I summarize the values in a time intervall of every line to one line. The values of a metric that no longer exists should also be taken into the sum values.
I tried to explain this in pic:
[image]

How can I summarize the values to one line?

Thank you very much for your hints
Ann

Comment: hello @markalex. Thank you for you comments and hints. Regarding my first problem I wrote an answer.

Comment: @markalex Yes. now i get a constant line. Thank you very much for the quick help. For my second problem I will think about this again.

Answer (score 0):

You can "stretch" last known value of the metric over time with function [`last_over_time`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time).

For your description you can use query like this:

```
sum by (namespace) (last_over_time(application_my_messages_total[30d]))
```

Notice, here metric will be carried for 30 days after it was last seen, and then disregarded. It's unclear from question how much do you actually need, so adjust accordingly.

Comment: @@markalex I edited the second part of my issue and I hope I explained it better.

Comment: I did it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76820053/prometheus-bar-chart-monthly