# Prometheus: bar chart (monthly)

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am a newbie in Prometheus and promql and I have this problem:

I want to display my values as a bar chart.
This picture shows what I want:
[image]

How can I create this bar chart with promql?

Thank you very much for your hints
Ann

Comment: Neither Grafana, nor Prometheus are not the right tool for "accountant type" periods like month: Prometheus is lacking range selector modifier "month" for a reason. Consider using periods of `30d` instead of calendar months.

Comment: Query like `last_over_time((process_cpu_seconds_total and on() (day_of_month()==1 and hour()==0 and minute()==0))[1d:])
- last_over_time((process_cpu_seconds_total and on() (day_of_month() ==1 and hour()==0 and minute()==0))[3d:] offset 30d)` (here `process_cpu_seconds_total` is just an example) might give you some start in investigation on how this can be done.